# Is there a way to list recent buffer history?

Tags: buffers

I just started using buffers in Vim and I couldn't figure out how to list recent closed buffers. Is there a simple way (like `:ls`) to list those? Are they actually stored by Vim?

Maybe I'm misusing buffers, but what I want to do is to glance at recent closed buffers and then reopen (`:e`) one of those (of which at that moment I don't remember the (file)name).

I searched `windows.txt` (from `:help buffers`) for terms like `history`, `closed buffer`, `buffer closed`, but none of them got me closer to doing what I want.

---

**Edit:** I tried `:oldfiles` (as [D. Ben Knoble](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/10604/d-ben-knoble) suggested) but that doesn't seem to work as I'd expect. When I'm viewing one file (buffer) `A.file` and open another one `B.file` (using NERDTree) and just after that I close `B.file`, then `:oldfiles` doesn't show `B.file` on the list.

Comment: You could try `:oldfiles`—depends on what you mean by “closed”

Comment: Read the docs `:h :oldfiles`...it explains exactly how it works. You can force it to behave a bit closer to expectations by jumping through some hacks...cough...hoops.

Comment: @BLayer I don't follow. I understood that what `:oldfiles` does is based on the `viminfo` file, but I'm not sure how would I accomplish what I asked. Are you suggesting putting each new buffer filename inside `viminfo` automatically with some script? I guess it's possible to use some hook whenever a new buffer is created, but I have no idea how to do any of that.

Comment: Yeah,  you're pretty much in the ballpark. I wasn't necessarily recommending such a route but figured I'd mention it regardless. I'll be away the rest of (my) evening. If no better solutions are in the offing by tomorrow perhaps I'll dig that hole a little deeper and see what can be found.

Comment: Did you try `buffers`? As you open new files they get added to the bottom of the list (most recent). You can see buffers no longer "visible" aka hidden" `:help buffers` has a legend. 

This was the answer for me when I was looking to reopen the last file I had open after I had accidentally opened another file over my active window.

Answer (score 5):

As of patch [8.1.2225](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/52410575be50d5c40bbe6380159df48cfc382ceb), you can use `:ls t` to list buffers in order of most recently used.

This includes "closed" buffers where closed means not in any window currently.  It does not include buffers from prior closed instances of vim.

Answer (score 1):

Use `_u`  to open last buffer,`_U` to view last buffers.

It can be improved.

```
let g:lastWindows= []
let g:lastWinName = ""

function! SaveLastWindow()
  if &bt == '' || &bt == 'help' || &ft == 'netranger' "|| &bt == 'nofile'
    let cur= expand( '<afile>' )

    if cur == g:lastWinName || cur ==""
      return
    endif 

    call add(g:lastWindows,cur) 

    let g:lastWinName=cur
  endif
endfunction 

augroup bufclosetrack
  au!
  autocmd BufWinLeave * call SaveLastWindow()
augroup END

function! LastWindow()
  exe "split " . g:lastWinName
endfunction

command -nargs=0 LastWindow call LastWindow()

nmap _u :LastWindow<CR>
nmap _U :call fzf#vim#cust_history(g:lastWindows)<CR>
```

in autoload/fzf/vim.vim add

```
function! fzf#vim#cust_history(src,...)
  return s:fzf('history-files', {
  \ 'source':  a:src,
  \ 'options': ['-m', '--header-lines', !empty(expand('%')), '--prompt', 'Hist> ']
  \}, a:000)
endfunction
```

Comment: My answer is based on https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/9081/reopen-the-most-recently-closed-buffer  @John O'M answer , that is also relevant. The question is a similar question.

Comment: After patch 8.1.2225 this could be simplified using the lastused field of getbufinfo()

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: e.g., getting a list of buffers sorted by recency, `getbufinfo()->sort({x,y -> y.lastused - x.lastused})->map({_,x -> x.name})->filter('len(v:val)')`

Comment: If a buffer is deleted, it is deleted from the buffer list as well. I agree it doesn't happen often. Also, I am on nvim. no lastused for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to improve my naive attempt:

```
"" if you want real list
" let g:mru_buffers = []
"" or just a string with newlines
let g:mru_buffers = ""
func! RecordMRU(file)
    if a:file != '' " here you can add another check if buffer/file is in mru and either do nothing or move it in the list/string to top
        " call insert(g:mru_buffers, a:file)
        let g:mru_buffers .= a:file . "\n"
    endif
endfunc
augroup mru_list | au!
    au BufDelete * call RecordMRU(expand('<afile>'))
augroup end
```

Having this you can list recently closed buffers with `echo g:mru_buffers`, or make a command `:command MRU :echo g:mru_buffers`.

It doesn't have persistence but one can easily add it.